# Causal inference with (only) interval uncertainty?

Tags: causality, interval-arithmetic

The modern popular frameworks that I am aware of for causal inference (i.e. potential outcomes or Pearlian) are based on a premise of uncertainty quantified as probability. There's nothing particularly wrong with that, but I like to explore tools and use cases.

[Interval arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic) (IA) is a way of quantifying/qualifying uncertainty. Some advantages I have found with implementing interval arithmetic include:

- Tends to be more comprehensible to non-technical audiences than probability.
- Intervals can be assigned according to background information (similar to causal inference and Bayesian inference).
- Calculations for propagation of uncertainty are *often* simple (esp. for monotonic functions)

IA is not a general replacement for probability however, and has some disadvantages of its own:

- Multiplication across addition is subdistributive (which can confuse people)
- The [dependency problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic#Dependency_problem)
- Division with intervals covering zero leads to splitting the problem into multiple subproblems can be tedious.
- Finding a tightest interval for the image of a function is tantamount to solving an optimization problem, and optimization problems can get very technical or even infeasible.
- Ignores degree of uncertainty within or outside interval.

Further, it can be combined with probability theory (e.g. [pboxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_box)).

But I was thinking about causal inference with intervals only. Has this been researched? If so, I would love a starting paper/book to start reading up on that literature.

Comment: It's an interesting approach I was not aware of. I think, however, it should be relatively straightforward. There are 3 assumptions that allow interpreting associations causally: consistency, positivity, and exchangeability. The latter is most relevant when modeling the outcome and it's an assumption of the potential outcome *distribution*. There has been pretty straightforward [extensions to quantile regression](https://arxiv.org/abs/2207.05940), so I'm optimistic it should also hold for interval arithmetic.

Comment: Very cool idea! I'm used to seeing DAGs define how to factorize a joint probability distribution. If we start from there, it seems natural to stick with probability distributions all the way - at what stage would IA come in?

Comment: @Scriddie I think you've hit the nail on the head. The only thing that seems to remain when probability theory is removed from Pearlian causal inference and replaced with interval arithmetic is that the DAG can be used to encode "which variables listen to which other variables".

Comment: This reminds me of [conformal prediction](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2107.07511.pdf), which in theory can be applied to any estimator. But that would be essentially an add-on to causal effect estimation, rather than operating in interval-space directly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of anything using Interval Arithmetic, but perhaps the idea behind [invariant causal prediction](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.01332) comes close. The way it's described and implemented in the article it's still very much rooted in probabilities, but the fundamental idea of invariant prediction could probably also be encoded using another measure of invariance that does not rely on probability distributions.